# How do I process text before I hand it over to enscript? (Or how do I print UTF8 Mutt messages to PDF?)

Tags: pdf, mutt, unicode, text, enscript

I'm trying to use `enscript` to print PDFs from Mutt, and hitting character encoding issues with curly quotes. So that an email with text like this:

```
“very dirty”    
we’re
```

Comes out as:

```
â\200\234very dirtyâ\200\235
weâ\200\231re
```

My print script currently reads like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
INPUT="$1" PDIR="$HOME/Desktop" OPEN_PDF=evince



tmpfile="`mktemp $PDIR/mutt_XXXXXXXX.pdf`"
enscript --font=Courier8 $INPUT -2r --word-wrap --fancy-header=mutt -p - 2>/dev/null | ps2pdf - $tmpfile
$OPEN_PDF $tmpfile >/dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 1
rm $tmpfile
```

Is there a way to replace the curly quotes before I send it to `enscript`? Or a character encoding I can use that will handle the quotes?

If there's another (better?) way to print to PDF from Mutt, I'm all ears. I just need to ensure that my quotes aren't getting fouled up.

Comment: FWIW, the hack I settled on for this particular case (printing from Mutt, primarily concerned with curly quotes) was to create a series of sed filters I could call from `.muttrc` with `set display_filter="sed -f /path/to/file"`

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently, `enscript` doesn't support UTF-8 files](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2014-October/052678.html).

What you may want to do is use `sed` to change the quotes before they go into enscript.

This will change the fancy quotes to the standard `"` and `'`. You won't be able to get them back after they're converted. To do this, you can insert a line like the following, just above the enscript line:

```
sed -i "s/[”“]/\"/g; s/[‘’]/'/g" $tmpfile
```

You may also be able to use `iconv` to convert the text to some other encoding, but I don't know much about that program. May be worth looking into.

Comment: I wish! I tried that first and hit walls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698444/how-do-i-use-sed-to-alter-a-variable-in-a-bash-script (And I'm fine with losing the fancy quotes for good -- that's definitely preferable to `â\200\234`

Comment: That SO exchange doesn't include trying to run `sed` using `$tmpfile` as the input but I tried that and I'm getting the same result.